# An issue occurred configuring root project 'android'

Tags: android, ionic2

I've read all posts having same issue, none resolved this. I am totally new to Ionic (I have some knowledge about Crodova and intelXdk but not Ionic).

I followed some tutorials to get my first app running. Firstly, it was running fine (of course, it had only texts :D ) then I started trying to make facebook login in the App.

I wasn't able to test this in Chrome as the facebook and storage are both Native dependencies, and could be not tested in a computer. Thus , I started trying to build the android app in order to test this in my phone and everytime I launch "ionic run android" I get this :

ionic run android --stacktrace

```
> ionic-app-base@0.0.0 ionic:build /home/chaibi/Bureau/foody
> ionic-app-scripts build "--stacktrace"

[16:14:53]  ionic-app-scripts 1.3.7 
[16:14:53]  build dev started ... 
[16:14:53]  clean started ... 
[16:14:53]  clean finished in 4 ms 
[16:14:53]  copy started ... 
[16:14:53]  transpile started ... 
[16:14:55]  transpile finished in 2.34 s 
[16:14:55]  preprocess started ... 
[16:14:55]  deeplinks started ... 
[16:14:55]  deeplinks finished in 19 ms 
[16:14:55]  preprocess finished in 21 ms 
[16:14:55]  webpack started ... 
[16:14:55]  copy finished in 2.64 s 
[16:15:04]  webpack finished in 8.52 s 
[16:15:04]  sass started ... 
[16:15:05]  sass finished in 1.10 s 
[16:15:05]  postprocess started ... 
[16:15:05]  postprocess finished in 6 ms 
[16:15:05]  lint started ... 
[16:15:05]  build dev finished in 12.07 s 
[16:15:07]  lint finished in 2.37 s 
ANDROID_HOME=/home/chaibi/Android/Sdk

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.

    at build_2h23ogq2gf6aqvti7pywfv5r2.run(/home/chaibi/Bureau/foody/platforms/android/build.gradle:137)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.



BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.822 secs

Error: /home/chaibi/Bureau/foody/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I am using Ionic 2.2, openjdk-8 and developping using WebStorm

Comment: is this the first time you are compiling any ionic app and do you have android studio installed already or android emulator ?

Comment: if that is the case then go to https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html download the sdk tools for windows unzip it and paste it here `C:\Users\[YOU USER NAME]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools` and it will work

Comment: Hey warlock, the sdk is installed, and I think I mentionned using Ubuntu :)

Comment: you have android emulator command line tools installed, strange this fixed my issue I had similar one

Comment: `openjdk-8`.. I suggest you install oracle java for android dev..